# Ignited Datatable add column for auto increment field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I follow [this](http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/) tutorial and it works, but how to add **No** field which is *autoincrement*

```
No | date              | total_sent_status|
---+-------------------+------------------+
1  |2013-12-26 00:00:00|         3        |
---+-------------------+------------------+
2  |2018-10-21 00:00:00|         3        |
---+-------------------+------------------+
```

**Note:**

the **No** record is a php looping not record from database
before I used Ignited Datatables, but now Im stuck, is anyone have the same 
experience before? thank you

Comment: which field you want as auto increment

Comment: 'No' field sir .. its just a number which in php loop like $no++

Comment: In db, just create no field as a autoincrement. Already it is in tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it while initialising the datatable. Refer https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

You can also do the same in fnRowCallback.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
       var index = iDisplayIndex +1;
       $('td:eq(0)',nRow).html(index);
       return nRow;
    }
  } );
} );
```